# Find all normal subgroups of the following

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

a) $\mathbb{Z}$

b) $\mathbb{Z}$/60$\mathbb{Z}$

c) $U(24)$ i.e. the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z}$/24$\mathbb{Z}$

d) Quaternion group

e) $S_3$.

For a) I think it is all subgroups of the form $n\mathbb{Z}$ since $\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian and also since $\mathbb{Z}$/60$\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian there would be as many normal subgroups as there are subgroups.
However, I'm wondering if there is a method to quickly pinpoint the normal subgroups for the other groups like we can for finding subgroups for finite groups. How can I find all normal subgroups efficiently?

Comment: Most of your groups are abelian. You observed that this is the case for a) and b), but it is also the case for c). If it is abelian, all subgroups are normal subgroups. For $S_3$, you do not have many subgroups and should be able to check by hands which ones are normal. The quaternion group is a bit more complicate. By the way, if it is a home-work, you should add the tag.

Comment: Quaternion group usually stand for the group $Q_8$, a group of order 8 and should be able to check by hands too.

Answer (score 2):

In general there is no quick way to determine *all* the normal subgroups. Especially when the groups $G$ get larger you better use a tool like $GAP$, see [here](http://www.gap-system.org/). You can always start with the usual suspects: the center of the group $Z(G)$, the commutator subgroup $G'$, etc.. For instance, in the case of $G=Q_8=\{±1,±i,±j,±k\}$, the center equals the commutator subgroup equals $\{-1,1\}$. And if $\{1\} \lneq N \lhd Q_8$, then $|G/N| \leq 4$, hence $G/N$ is abelian and $G' \subseteq N$. This limits your search by hand.